# How to search a JSON Object for the selected date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script src="content/personSchedule.js"></script>
var personSchedule = [
    {
        "date": "02/6/2017",
        "title": "CEO",
        "mondayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Apple Campus PM"
    },
    {
        "date": "02/13/2017",
        "title": "CEO",
        "mondayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Apple Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Apple Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Apple Campus PM"
    }
];
```

I have a date picker

```
<input type="date" id="date" step="7" min="2017-02-06" />
```

when the date changes, I want to change the text that appears in the HTML

```
$("#date").change(function(){
    var theSelectedDate = $('#date').val();
    console.log(theSelectedDate);
    $.each(json.people.person, function(i, v) {
        if (v.name.search(new RegExp(/theSelectedDate/)) != -1) {
            alert(v.title);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

When I run this I get the following error

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /**

Comment: You ca use `<input type="week">` although be aware that its value is in format YYYY-Wnn (2017-W06) (year-Wweeknumber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to do something like:

```
function getOjectForDate(date){
    return myArray.filter(function(value){
        return value.date == date
    })
}
console.log(getOjectForDate(input.val())  //  returns array with every valid object
```

If you want to get only one value or undefined, use `Array.find` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Where myArray is the JSON object, and input being the input

Comment: <script src="content/personSchedule.js"></script> is where the JSON file is stored. It looks like a JSON Object is stored in the var personSchedule

Comment: Once you parse the JSON you can use the function `Array.find` to find your value. Or in this case use instead of myArray the presonalSchedule variable.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `/theSelectedDate`, I think it should be `/theSelectedDate/` or some other RegExp format.

Comment: Thanks I get no error but I am not getting any results. My alert is not firing when I know it should

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex pattern is wrong: supposed to be like new `RegExp(/ab+c/, 'i');` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

In your case you want `RegExp(thSelectedDate)` since you are passing value to the `RegExp()` and that function automatically evaluates the value by appending `\` in front and back of it.